MAUI Xamarin: After choosing a line in autocomplete field , to be able to fill in another field automatically
Thank you very much for your time,
I have little experience in developing applications in MAUI and I'm trying to make a small application for mobile devices for personal use.
To make some imputs I'm using the components of the “.NET MAUI and Xamarin Controls” package, and at the moment I'm having a problem that I'd like you to help with.
I have a view that has an autocomplete, in the list it shows the name and telephone number, without any problem.
enter image description here
What I wanted to do was, after choosing a line in autocomplete field , to be able to fill in another field automatically with the telephone number.
This is the code file xaml
enter image description here
Can you help me with a little example? I think it should be easy to solve, but with my lack of experience I'm not managing.

Please do not post code as images

Try binding both controls to the same SelectedItem property

Are you binding both controls to the same SelectedItem?

Can you add the relevant code in the .cs file？ I need to confirm that the binding data is correct
